# Can I use a subquery to choose the column I want to select in SQL in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a query written that will return a single record (a class number) from table1.  This class number is the title of a column that I want to select in another table (table2). I want to use this subquery as a mechanism to select this column. Can this be done?

I know this may be bad design but I am just wondering if this sort of thing is possible in MS Access SQL.  I know it is not as powerful as MySQL.

Comment: Are these local Access tables?  Or are you linking to SQL Server or MYSQL (note: these are different)

Comment: This is not possible in any database, unless you use dynamic SQL or a giant `case`/`iff` statement.

Comment: That's certainly possible (and simple) if you generate the SQL at runtime using VBA.  Are you looking for a SQL-only solution?

Comment: Oh.  And you're right.  It smells like terrible design.

Comment: I am looking for a SQL only solution but not opposed to using VBA. Gordon could you elaborate on the case / iff statement?

Comment: Local access tables.  Not linking to SQL Server, actually linking to an Excel Spreadsheet that is being treated as a table.

Comment: Let me know what you guys think of this idea:  Run first query to get class number based on user input, store this as variable in VBA, and then insert that in a VBA generated query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you're ever going to do this is using VBA to write the SQL, which really isn't a bad thing.  I'd do it sort of like this:

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset
Dim MyVar = String '(or whatever the datatype is for ClassNumber in Table1)
Dim sSQL as String
Dim qdfNew As DAO.QueryDef
Dim qryLoop As QueryDef

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT ClassNumber from Table1")

MyVar = rec(0)

'First check to see if the query already exists.  If so, delete it.
For Each qryLoop In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
If qryLoop.Name = MyVar Then
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, MyVar 
End If
Next

'This will select only the field that relates to the ClassNumber above
sSQL = "SELECT " & MyVar & " FROM Table2"

Set qdfNew = db.CreateQueryDef("MyNewQuery", sSQL)
```

Then, MyNewQuery is a permanent query in your database which can be used in other queries.

Comment: Can the query be overridden?  For example each time I want to get a different class number.  I am prompting the user for information to determine the result of the first query.

Comment: You can put a little block of code in there that checks to see if the query already exists, and deletes it if it exists.  Otherwise, it will just jump to the section that creates it.  Then, you can run it over and over and it will always have the current data in it.

Comment: See my edited code above.  Keep in mind this is "aircode" and untested, but it should be pretty close.

Comment: Last question:  does this go in a module or a macro? And yeah I understand it is just scrapped together.  I have a CS degree, I think I should be able to figure it out.

Comment: You can make it a Function and call it from a macro, or you can put it in a module behind a form and call it on a button click.  Either one should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a better option, but I can only think of:

1. Heinous case statement to choose the right column.
2. Using VBA.
3. Correcting the table design, turning the field name into a value
       that can be joined upon.